# Sending email to those who are members of the Office 365 group

Tags: email, office365, exchange

Office 365 group is available. This group was created over Teams and has an e-mail address test@domain.com.

Since this group was created over Teams, it was added by an authorized member via Teams.

The mails sent to the problem group mail address do not reach the group members.

To solve the problem, there is an option called "subscribe new members" in the exchange group settings. When it is activated, the newly added member is sent by mail. Or when a user has been removed and added.

But when we consider that there are more than 50 groups, we think that this is not a very healthy and logical method.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: There is no need to use salutations, they decrease the site's transparency. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 0):

When creating a Microsoft 365 group in Outlook or SharePoint, the group mailbox is visible in Outlook. When creating a team in Teams, the group mailbox is hidden by default. You can use the Set-UnifiedGroup cmdlet with the HiddenFromExchangeClientsEnabled parameter to make a mailbox visible.

[How Microsoft 365 Groups work with Teams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/office-365-groups#how-microsoft-365-groups-work-with-teams)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Thanks for your understanding and support.